# How to hide or remove the title bar of terminal in centos?

Tags: centos, centos-6, gnome-terminal

Want to remove the titlebar of the terminal. It would helpful if there is a way to generically do it for all the windows ? If not possible, still if it would be helpful if I can remove or hide the titlebar for the terminal itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Title bar provides essential interface for the window (close, minimize/maximize, restore buttons and window name). I seriously doubt that it can be removed. And the reason for that is obvious

Comment: Most of the time I work with a terminal and a browser. As such title bar takes space. And the information is kind of redundant to me, while actions I use keyboard shortcuts.

At the moment I am using full screen. Just curious if it there is a way to do that. 

To each his own.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75284/remove-titlebar-from-maximized-terminal-window) will help (I know it is for Ubuntu, but there's some good info)

Comment: And do please tell the reason which is obvious.

Comment: It is possible to do so, Chromium does it and xfce-terminal too (added answer on how to do for xfce-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which terminal you use, but on xfce4-terminal, you go to menu **Edit** -> **Preferences**, select **View** tab and under **Opening new windows** section, there is an option to disable system title bar for future terminal (not for the one already open but for all new ones). Next to it there are options to disable menu bar and toolbar as well as the size for new windows.

Comment: I am using GNOME Terminal 2.31.3.

Comment: If I remember well, gnome-terminal didn't had this option when I was using it... only to remove menu bar.